# xamarin shared preferences replace

Tags: android, xamarin, replace

I am new on xamarin android development and i have a problem with return shared preferences getString method.

```
ISharedPreferences pref = PreferenceManager.GetDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
            string loginToken = pref.GetString("token", string.Empty);
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(loginToken))
            {
                this result return=> "\"QuZzOXjLead6rmBuSjs6vJ269BKmiXvOKPmy47y46ms\""
```

and replace method not worked. How can i clear "\" and \"" symbols?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\" is just an escaping for " - so just do a string.Replace("\"", "")